# What is the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ under the $\mathbb Q$ equivalent probability measure?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent standard random variables. Let $\theta$ be a
> constant with $\theta^2 \in (0, 1)$ and define the $\mathbb P$-equivalent probability measure, $\mathbb Q$, by
> $\frac{d\mathbb Q}{d\mathbb P}=\frac{e^{\theta XY}}{\mathbb E[e^{\theta XY}]}>0$. What is the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ under $\mathbb Q$? Are $(X,Y)$ also independent under $\mathbb Q$?

---

My try:

Compute that
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X<x_0, Y<y_0)&=\frac {1}{\mathbb E(e^{\theta XY})}\int_{-\infty}^{x_0}dx\int_{-\infty}^{y_0} e^{\theta xy}\frac 1{2\pi}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi\mathbb E(e^{\theta XY})}\int_{-\infty}^{x_0}e^{-x^2/2}dx\int_{-\infty}^{y_0}e^{-\frac 12(y-\theta x)^2-\frac 12\theta^2 x^2}dy
\end{align}
Let $t=y-\theta x$, then
$$ \mathbb P(X<x_0, Y<y_0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\mathbb E(e^{\theta XY})}\int_{-\infty}^{x_0}e^{-\frac 12x^2-\frac 12\theta^2 x^2}dx\int_{-\infty}^{y_0-\theta x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac 12 t^2}dy. $$

But I have not idea how to proceed. Also, the hint says maybe we can consider the moment generating function but we have the same type of issue that we cannot seperate $e^{\theta xy}$ and use the independence of $X$ and $Y$ under $\mathbb P$.

Comment: Hint: $f_Q(x,y) = \dfrac{1}{2 \pi \mathbb{E}[e^{\theta XY}]}  \exp \left( - \dfrac{1}{2} (x^2 + y^2 - 2 \theta xy) \right)$ and $(x^2 + y^2 - 2 \theta xy) = z^T A z$ where $z = [x \ y]$ and $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -\theta \\ - \theta & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. Does it ring a bell? (I just hope I have interpreted the meaning of joint distribution under $\mathbb{Q}$ correctly)

Comment: @sudeep5221 So we can change the variables($(x-\theta y, y)$) by an orthogonal matrix and get the density function the multiplication of two density of independent normal variables. But how to see whether they are dependent? Are they also bivariate normal? I think it is:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables#:~:text=Independent%20random%20variables,-Let%20X%20and&text=This%20means%20that%20the%20sum,squares%20of%20the%20standard%20deviations). But they have different variances. So how to determine independence?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to consider the moment generating function approach, compute the MGF by conditioning on  (say) $X$. This permits you to "separate" the $XY$. If $E$ denotes expectation under $P$ and $E_Q$ expectation under $Q$, then
$$
\begin{align}
E_Q\exp(sX+tY)&=k(\theta)E\exp(sX+tY+\theta XY)\\
& = k(\theta)E\left[ E\left(\exp(sX+tY+\theta XY)\mid X\right)\right]\\
& =k(\theta)E\exp\left(sX + \frac12(t+\theta X)^2\right),
\end{align}
$$
the last equality using the univariate MGF $E\exp (uY)=\exp \frac12( u^2 )$ when $Y$ is standard normal:
$$\begin{aligned}
E(\exp(sX+tY+\theta XY\mid X=x)&=E(\exp(sx+tY+\theta xY\mid X=x)]\\
&=E(\exp(sx+tY+\theta xY))\\
&=e^{sx}E(\exp((t+\theta x)Y)\\
&=e^{sx}e^{(t+\theta x)^2/2}
\end{aligned}
$$ Now you are left with a straightforward expectation involving $X\sim N(0,1)$, which, when the smoke clears, should represent the MGF of a  familiar bivariate distribution (also hinted at by the comment by @sudeep5221 and the answer by @ChristopherK). To perform the expectation you can prove and use the fact
$$
E\exp\left(\frac a2X^2+bX+c\right) = \exp\left(c +\frac{b^2}{2(1-a)}\right)
$$
when $X$ is standard normal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am confused with your computation, can you explain where is the exponential function from the $k(\theta)E\exp(sX+tY+\theta XY)= k(\theta)E\left[ E(sX+tY+\theta XY\mid X)\right]$ and why does $Y$ disappear in $
k(\theta)E\exp\left(sX + \frac12(t+\theta X)^2\right)$?

Comment: @Bach Sorry, that was a typographical error. I left out the exponential in that equation you mentioned. The equation is the law of iterated expectations: $E \exp(\cdot) = E [ E(\exp(\cdot )\mid X)]$. The $Y$ disappears in the next line after evaluating the inner conditional expectation:

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused, how do you evaluate the inner conditional expectation?

Comment: I have added additional detail.

Comment: Thank you! Now it is clearer. But how shall we proceed after that? We can change the variables and we can express the density function as the product of two density functions of some normal distribution. But I only know that mutually independent normal random variables with **common variance** remain mutually independent with common variance under orthogonal transformations. But here we do not have the same variance. Then we cannot claim that the inverse change of variables preserves independence.

Comment: The result should be a bivariate normal distribution where the variables are not independent. You can determine the means and variances and correlations by matching coefficients with the MGF $M_{X,Y}(t_{1},t_{2}) = \exp \left \{t_{1}\mu_{1}+t_{2}\mu_{2}+\frac{1}{2}(t_{1}^{2}\sigma_{1}^{2}+2t_{1}^{}t_{2}^{}\rho \sigma_{1}^{}\sigma_{2}^{}+t_{2}^{2}\sigma_{2}^{2})  \right \}$

Answer (score 0):

We know that $$d\mathbb{P}(x,y) = f_{X,Y}(x,y)\, dx\, dy = \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^{2}+y^{2})}\, dx\, dy.$$

We can also show that $$d\mathbb{Q}(x,y) = \frac{d\mathbb{Q}}{d\mathbb{P}}\, d\mathbb{P}(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi\mathbb{E}[e^{\theta xy}]} e^{\theta xy - \frac{1}{2}(x^{2}+y^{2})}\, dx\, dy.$$

Now we calculate $\mathbb{E}[e^{\theta xy}]$:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[e^{\theta xy}] &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\theta y)^{2} - \frac{1}{2}(1-\theta^{2})y^{2}}\, dx\, dy  \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(1-\theta^{2})y^{2}}\, dy \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\theta^{2}}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-z^2/2}\, dz \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\theta^{2}}}.
\end{align*}

Now deduce that
$$d\mathbb{Q}(x,y) = \frac{\sqrt{1-\theta^{2}}}{2\pi} e^{\theta xy - \frac{1}{2}(x^{2}+y^{2})}\, dx\, dy.$$

Comment: But I think I am supposed to get something that is more compact.